# selenium tests stuck and not running

Tags: java, selenium, testng

I am using selenium to test a web app, all tests written in java go well on linux (mint mate), but when I try to launch the very same tests on windows 7, in some point it stops and don't do anything, it seems as they stuck. Not all tests, some runs well.

I am using IntelliJ Idea (if it matters) project and pretty same jdk ( 1.7.0_07 on linux and 1.7.0_09 on windows) on both machines.

I can't see any serious differences between tests which are OK and tests which aren't. I can only guess, that problem is inside TestNG assertions, because on debugging it ends somewhere within it. Maybe somebody met with that problem before?

Comment: Don't you get an exception or something?

Comment: No, it just keep running without any progress, as if I use while(true) somewhere in code.

Comment: Do you wait for something to appear?

Comment: Well, yes, for about 10 minutes i am waiting, hoping that it is some selenium search issues, then I finish it manually.

Comment: Your guess is right, sort of. I was using firefox 15.0.1 on linux and firefox 17 on windows, as soon as i downloaded older version and installed it, everything become normal. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you write an answer what solved you question or delete the Q if you think no one else will have this problem again!? thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in different versions of firefox on windows and linux machines, though I was using same version of selenium on both. If you get the same issue check the versions first, it can save you time.